# Copy initialization not work?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        cout << "Default constructor called." << endl;
    }
    Test(Test &obj) {
        cout << "copy constructor called." << endl;
    }
    Test& operator=(const Test &obj) {
        cout << "copy assignment called." << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Test() {
        cout << "destructor called." << endl;
    }
};

Test func(Test test) {
    cout << "func called" << endl;
    return test;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test t1;
    Test t2 = func(t1); // No matching constructor for initialization for 'Test'
    return 0;
}
```

I am learning c++. I wrote some test code to understand copy initialization and copy assignment. Now I can not figure out why the second assignment can not work.

Comment: The copy constructor signature is wrong, should be `Test(const Test& obj)` not `Test(Test& obj)`

Comment: The compiler tells you loud and clear: "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Test&’ ". So, make your parameter of the copy constructor a const reference (which is the normal case) and it will work.

Comment: @Galik Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An [rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue) cannot be modified**, and should, in this case, be treated as a const reference `const Test& obj`. So when you convert `t1` into the `test` in `func`, it's OK because `t1` is an lvalue, but not when you're constucting `t2` from the return value, which is an xvalue (categorized into rvalue).

In short, the signature of your copy constructor is wrong because it only accepts lvalues.

The following patch on line 10 makes the code work for me.

```
Test(const Test &obj) {
     ^~~~~
```

Here's the article about [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) on cppreference.com. See **Syntax** section.
Also the [rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue) article, which reads

> An rvalue may be used to **initialize a const lvalue reference**, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends.

---

---

P.S. You can use move semantics (C++11), too, which accept rvalues only. It's not hard to write a move constructor like this:

```
Test(Test&& obj) ...
```

Comment: Copy constructors are allowed to modify the source object, and they do not have to accept a const reference.

Comment: @M.M Suddenly realized what went wrong. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor allows the object being copied to be modified.

The statement

```
Test t2 = func(t1);
```

will store the return value of `func()` in a temporary, and then copy that into `t2`.   However, that requires a copy constructor that accepts a `const` reference, since a temporary cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference.

(Technically, the compiler is allowed to elide the temporary, but it is still required to issue diagnostics for your code assuming it has created the temporary.  In other words, the copy constructor must be `const`).

Change your copy constructor to accept a `const` reference.

```
Test(Test const &obj) {
```